# Framework error on cloudflare global network

Tags: cloudflare, portforwarding, cloudflare-pages

I'm using next.js framework to build a website and I want to deploy that to Cloudflare. When I type the build commands, after building it, it says `Running at localhost:PORT` but it doesn't deploy to Cloudflare global network. Are there any ways to fix it?

I tried using `npm run build && npm run start` but it just doesn't deploy to Cloudflare global network.